# How do I add entire class folder to outbound change set

Tags: change-set

I'm trying to delete an Apex class from production. I've read the instructions on how to do so with IDE but I'm not sure what that is.

But the instructions on how to do that just from the sandbox don't seem to be working. Everything here is in sandbox.

I deleted the class.
I created a new outbound change set.
When I try to add to the change set I don't see any options to move the entire Apex Class. When I select 'Apex Class' in the dropdown I just get a message "There are no remaining components of the selected type available to add to your change set."

Answer (score 2):

You can not delete classes using changesets. You will need to use one of following

1) Eclipse IDE
2) Ant Migration tool
3) Metadata API

More details are on this thread [best way to delete unused apex classes and triggers in production](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23229/best-way-to-delete-unused-apex-classes-and-triggers-in-production)