# Cause :UNKNOWN EXCCEPTION, Invalid Cross Reference ID During ANT undeployCode

Tags: deployment, ant, package, destructivechanges.xml

I am trying to remove a class from my QAT using destructive.xml ANT script and getting the following exception.

> Failed to process the request successfully. Cause(UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION): INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY: invalid cross reference id

Below is My Package.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<types>
    <members>TestUndeployCodeQAT</members>
    <name>ApexClass</name>
</types>
<version>29.0</version>
</Package>
```

Comment: If you are lucky, adding -`d` and `-v` to the [ant command-line](https://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html) might  reveal something.

Comment: I would need to see your ANT script / folder setup. If you are ok with not using ANT then you might want to create 2 files, use Workbench, and this answer: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/155219/10073

Comment: Problem is that this specific error can come for many cases. It's more like general exception during the deployment.  Since, it's destrctiveChanges, might be that the class is being used somewhere. Try to create dummyClass, and delete it with ant. This can give you indication if the issue is in the ant configuration or specifically in the class you try in the first place.